How to test web REST server
I'm currently writing a REST web server with Rust.
I'm using "reqwest" to test the REST API. To get these tests running, I need to have an instance of the server running.
If I launch it before running "cargo test", cargo fails as it can overwrite the binary (on Windows)
So, I've tried to:

run the server with ("cargo run") before running the tests
stop the server after all test are run.

For 1), I've found several solution (test_env_helpers, Once, ...)
But for 2), I haven't found a solution. I've tried:

test_env_helpers: the "after_all" method is called before all the tests are run
static_int + "#[dynamic(drop)]" the Drop method is not called
suitest: the "after_all" is called, but only one test is run in each test module

Any suggestion?

Have you considered running the test client and web server in the same executable? You could, for example, run the server on a separate thread or async task and use a Condvar or a oneshot channel to wait for it to finish starting. For multiple tests, pick a unique port for each.

You didn't specify your web server framework, but you seem adamant to run the server binary itself and keep it running over the full test suite. I would generally do neither; most web server frameworks have more sensible ways for testing routing and handlers.

My web server framework is Rocket+Diesel+PosgresSQL
I haven't consider running the server and the client in the same process.
To be honest, I don't really like this solution. I like a clear separation between application and tests.
Everything works at the exception of the server shutdown. What I'm missing is some kind of Drop for static variables. Or having some hooks in the cargo main function

One solution is to use an integration test. During cargo test, they're compiled separately from and have access to the server binary. You're responsible for figuring out the path to the binary, though. On supported operating systems, libc::atexit allows killing the server after tests have concluded.
// tests/test_server.rs
use libc::atexit;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::process::{Child, Command, Stdio};
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub fn ensure_server_started() {
    static STARTED: Mutex<Option<Child>> = Mutex::new(None);

    let mut started = STARTED.lock().unwrap();
    if started.is_some() {
        return;
    }
    let mut path = std::env::current_exe().unwrap();
    assert!(path.pop());
    if path.ends_with("deps") {
        assert!(path.pop());
    }

    // Note: Cargo automatically builds this binary for integration tests.
    path.push(format!(
        "{}{}",
        env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),
        std::env::consts::EXE_SUFFIX
    ));

    let mut cmd = Command::new(path);
    cmd.env_clear();
    cmd.stdin(Stdio::piped());
    cmd.stdout(Stdio::piped());
    cmd.stderr(Stdio::piped());
    // TODO: cmd.args([]);

    let mut server = cmd.spawn().unwrap();

    let stdout = server.stdout.take().unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
    let mut lines = reader.lines();

    let mut listening = false;
    while let Some(Ok(line)) = lines.next() {
        // TODO: Server needs to print "listening" to stdout
        if line.contains("listening") {
            listening = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    assert!(listening);

    extern "C" fn kill() {
        STARTED.lock().unwrap().as_mut().unwrap().kill().unwrap();
    }

    unsafe { atexit(kill) };

    *started = Some(server);
}

#[test]
pub fn test_server() {
    // Beginning of every test.
    ensure_server_started();

    // TODO: Test
}


Thanks. I'm already using integration tests. I have done something very similar for starting the server.
My problem is not with the starting of the server, but with how to stop it.
The server is used by several tests, not just one

@SergeWeinstock got it; updated answer!

Thanks. I got it working! I didn't know about atexit....
